# Dynamically checking mySQL database to see if a currenttime has passed a datetime stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, datetime, dynamic

basically i have a series of countdown timers for auctions on my site. i do this by storing the countdown end time in the database and use javascript to create the countdown. i was just wondering how i could have the web-server constantly check whether the countdown has finished and if is has, dynamically change the status of the auction from "not finished" to "finished". should i have a constantly running script on my web-server? that keeps querying the database to check if the countdown end-time has been reached?

p.s. im using apache, mySQL, and PHP

any views or help is appreciated!

Johnny

Answer (score 3):

Constantly checking would not scale at all. It's unlikely the end time would change, so you can just deliver the end times of each auction to the web page and use javascript to change the status to finished when that time reached.

Sure, someone could edit the javascript and change the end times, but the client is only for display. You can do one final call to the server at the end time to check if the auction was extended. The server remains that authority. Any submission still needs to be check against the server time, not whatever was displayed on the user computer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the logic goes like this

1. Load the default end time using database value and run counter through javascript.
2. when elapsed time is about to reach the auction end time say just 1 or 2 seconds before, you can check if the end time has changed and return the new value and feed it back to Javascript timer.

Above is applicable only if you increase end time for some reason.

If not than you can solely rely on javascript to count time for you and when end time is reached with javascript counter just make a quick ajax call to update your database (if it is required at all)

You should always load end time to your javascript function from your database